# How do I replace the stem of an outdoor frost-free faucet?

Tags: faucet

I'm replacing the faucet handle (below). But  I can't figure out how to remove the stem  (in photo above the red outlined area). So I'm thinking I need to remove the stem as well. But I can't see inside to see how to do that.

This [other answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/123005/how-to-remove-frost-free-outdoor-faucet-drain-valve-assembly) explains what the stem is, but not how it connects to the water source, or how to remove/replace it.

I'm also a little worried that if I get it disconnected I won't be able to reconnect it. (Right now the faucet works, it's just hard to close. If I break the stem, I'll have to leave the water off til a plumber visits!)

Photo taken from **above**. The water source is at top of photo (wall). Faucet handle is at bottom of photo.
[image]

Comment: Not a dupe. See update in my question. The other answer does not explain how to remove the STEM.

Comment: It looks like the white part slides off the stem. Have you tried that?

Comment: The white piece is a new piece but it isn't compatible with the black 'stopper' above it. The companion piece that white piece slides over the white piece is too loose over black piece and it leaks.